# VSTS SSH tasks uses STDERR

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

I am configuring release step with VSTS to update database and use SSH (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/ssh) to run our script to update mongodb.

Script **works just fine** but somehow all output goes to STDERR.

Run: **Inline Script**

Arguments:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/Project/root/Deploy
dos2unix sync_mongo.sh
sh ./mongosync.sh
```

Here is beginning for step log:

```
2018-01-18T17:39:55.7603461Z dos2unix sync_mongo.sh
2018-01-18T17:39:55.7603748Z sh ./mongosync.sh
2018-01-18T17:39:55.7604695Z Trying to setup SSH connection to ********@****:22
2018-01-18T17:39:57.5259303Z Successfully connected.
2018-01-18T17:39:59.7115141Z tr -d '\015' <"./sshscript_1516297195734" > "./sshscript_1516297195734._unix"
2018-01-18T17:40:00.0197880Z chmod +x "./sshscript_1516297195734._unix"
2018-01-18T17:40:00.2617249Z "./sshscript_1516297195734._unix"
2018-01-18T17:40:00.5124617Z ##[error]dos2unix: 
2018-01-18T17:40:00.5124929Z 
2018-01-18T17:40:00.5125475Z ##[error]converting file sync_mongo.sh to Unix format ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that many unix commands uses stderr to show progress.

Solution was to ignore stderr output:

```
dos2unix sync_mongo.sh 2> /dev/null
sh ./mongosync.sh 2> /dev/null
```